# Not able to create instance on new openstack

Tags: openstack-nova, openstack-keystone

While creating instance from horizon "zed" version Iam getting below error in nova.log.

```
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1141, in get
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi     return self.request(url, 'GET', **kwargs)
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 931, in request
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi     resp = send(**kwargs)
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1038, in _send_request
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi     raise exceptions.ConnectFailure(msg)
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi keystoneauth1.exceptions.connection.ConnectFailure: Unable to establish connection to https://controller/identity: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='controller', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /identity (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1703a3eb60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED'))
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/block_device.py", line 651, in get_bdm_image_metadata
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi     image_meta = image_api.get(context, image_id)
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/image/glance.py", line 1205, in get
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi     return session.show(context, image_id,
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/image/glance.py", line 287, in show
2023-05-30 22:24:12.985 2387910 ERROR nova.api.openstack.wsgi     _reraise_translated_image_exception(image_id)
```

Below is the config where the auth URL is specified.

```
[service_user]


send_service_user_token = true
auth_url = https://controller/identity
auth_strategy = keystone
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
user_domain_name = Default
username = nova
password = maprwins
```

I tried adding the :5000 to the auth_URL but it still fails with auth error.

Comment: The below works but instance creation fails.  


`
# openstack image list

+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name   | Status |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| 480ce16e-8a5b-4c52-9620-5d6dfee53398 | cirros | active |
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+
#

`

Comment: nothing is working on port 443 `# netstat -plant |grep -i 443  -w
~#`